# Cypress load environment variables in custom commands

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, cypress, dotenv

I'm building a Next.js app and write my tests using Cypress. I configure the environment variables using a [`.env.local` file](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables) locally. In the CI pipeline, they are defined normally.

I'm trying to write a custom command in Cypress that encrypts a session in `cypress/support/command.ts`.

```
import { encryptSession } from 'utils/sessions';

Cypress.Commands.add(
  'loginWithCookie',
  ({
    issuer = 'some-issuer',
    publicAddress = 'some-address',
    email = 'some-mail',
  } = {}) => {
    const session = { issuer, publicAddress, email };

    return encryptSession(session).then(token => {
      cy.setCookie('my-session-token', token);
      return session;
    });
  },
);
```

When this command runs, it fails because `encryptSession` uses a `TOKEN_SECRET` environment variable, that Cypress doesn't load.

```
import Iron from '@hapi/iron';

const TOKEN_SECRET = process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || '';

export function encryptSession(session: Record<string, unknown>) {
  return Iron.seal(session, TOKEN_SECRET, Iron.defaults);
}
```

How can I get Cypress to load the environment variables from that file, if its there (= only locally because the variables are defined in the CI - it should detect the other variables in the pipeline normally, so the equivalent of detecting a variable that has been set with `export MY_VAR=foo`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Cypress.env](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env.html), but you want to set the token on `process.env` which looks like it's not fully coordinated with the Cypress version.

I know that any `process.env` with a key with prefix of **CYPRESS_** ends up in `Cypress.env()`, but you want to go in the opposite direction.

I would use a task which gives you access to the file system and `process.env`,

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    checkEnvToken :() =>  {
      const contents = fs.readFileSync('.env.local', 'utf8'); // get the whole file
      const envVars = contents.split('\n').filter(v => v);    // split by lines 
                                                              // and remove blanks      
      envVars.forEach(v => {
        const [key, value] = v.trim().split('=');     // split the kv pair
        if (!process.env[key]) {                      // check if already set in CI
          process.env[key] = value;                        
        }
      })
      return null;                                    // required for a task
    },
  })
```

Call the task ahead of any tests, either in **/cypress/support/index.js**, or a `before()`, or in the custom command.

**In the custom command**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'loginWithCookie',
  ({
    issuer = 'some-issuer',
    publicAddress = 'some-address',
    email = 'some-mail',
  } = {}) => {
    cy.task('checkEnvToken').then(() => {  // wait for task to finish 

      const session = { issuer, publicAddress, email };

      return encryptSession(session).then(token => {
        cy.setCookie('my-session-token', token);
          return session;
        });
    })
  });
```

---

Digging into the code for `@hapi/iron`, there is a call to `crypto` which is a Node library, so you may need to move the whole `encryptSession(session)` call into a task to make it work.

```js
import { encryptSession } from 'utils/sessions';

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    encryptSession: (session) =>  {

      const contents = fs.readFileSync('.env.local', 'utf8'); // get the whole file
      const envVars = contents.split('\n').filter(v => v);    // split by lines 
                                                              // and remove blanks      
      envVars.forEach(v => {
        const [key, value] = v.trim().split('=');     // split the kv pair
        if (!process.env[key]) {                      // check if already set in CI
          process.env[key] = value;                        
        }
      })

      return encryptSession(session);                 // return the token
    },
  })
```

Call with

```
cy.task('encryptSession', { issuer, publicAddress, email })
  .then(token => {
    cy.setCookie('my-session-token', token);
  });
```

---

**Where to run the above cy.task**

I guess you only need to run it once per test session (so that it's set for a number of spec files) in which case the place to call it is inside a `before()` in **/cypress/support/index.js**.

The downside of placing it there is it's kind of hidden, so personally I'd put it inside a `before()` at the top of each spec file.

There's a small time overhead in the `fs.readFileSync` but it's minimal compared to waiting for page loads etc.

Comment: Thank you this looks good. My question is, would this code run only once, or would `fs.readFileSync` and the rest run everytime someone uses `loginWithCookie` (which calls `cy.task('encryptSession' ...)`? If it runs every time, is there a way to avoid that or is that fine?

Comment: I added a note above about running the task.

Comment: Running the `fs.readFileSync` in `support/index.ts` or in a `.spec` file crashes with `fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.readFileSync is not a function`.

Comment: I tried running the env setup in the `on` scope above the task definition, but that won't work either. For some reason then the task doesn't know about the env vars again ...

Comment: You still need to call the task - the bit that goes into the `before()` in support/index.js is the  bit in the section **Call with**.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Aaah I understand! So you're saying run `cy.loginWithCookie` in the `before()` hook and not the part that sets up the env vars using `fs`. I'm sorry, In my second comment I was trying to say that I tried putting the `fs` part in between the `pluginConfig`'s `(on, config)` and the `on('task', ...)` scope.

Comment: I think as you said, using the `before()` hook is as good as its going to get unfortunately, even though the process then runs multiple times. Thank you very much for your help! 

Answer (score 3):

Steve's answer actually helped me to end up with this code in `cypress/plugins/index.ts`.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({ path: '.env.local' });

import { encryptSession } from 'utils/sessions';

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
const pluginConfig: Cypress.PluginConfig = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    encryptSession: (session: {
      issuer: string;
      publicAddress: string;
      email: string;
    }) => encryptSession(session),
  });
};

export default pluginConfig;
```

Then in `cypress/support/commands.ts`.

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'loginWithCookie',
  ({
    issuer = 'some-issuer',
    publicAddress = 'some-address',
    email = 'some-email',
  } = {}) => {
    const session = { issuer, publicAddress, email };

    return cy.task<string>('encryptSession', session).then(token => {
      return cy.setCookie('my-secret-token', token).then(() => {
        return session;
      });
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: Looks good - could you show how it fits into (presume) plugins//index.js?